# How do I get files from a second project on an Azure DevOps Agent via tf.exe?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, tfvc

My build pipeline gets sources in the local sources folder via "Get sources". I would like to get some other files from a different project.

Conditions

- Azure DevOps Server on Premise
- Self hosted build agent
- TFVC (not git)
- There is an existing mapping in ..\w\XXX\s\ to $projectA\subdir\branch
- I want to get files from another project $projectB\subdir\branch
- $projectB is not mapped
- Only Powershell and tf.exe - I know the extra mapping function in the pipeline UI, but I would like to script that

I tried:

```
$collection = "well my collection..."
$tfsProjectTargetPath = "`$/projectB/subdir/branch"
$localWorkDir = $env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY
$workspaceName = $env:Build_Repository_Tfvc_Workspace
& $tf vc workfold /map /workspace:$workspaceName $localWorkDir /collection:$collection /noprompt
```

That runs into `"TF14061: The workspace ws_XXX_YYYY;user does not exist."`.

I also tried creating a new workspace:

```
$workspaceName = "some new name"
& $tf vc workspace /new /location:local /permission:Public $workspaceName /collection:$collection /noprompt
```

That runs into `"The path ..\w\220\s\projectA\subidr\branch is already mapped in workspace ws_XXX_YYYY;Build\<guid>"`.

To me it seems the value of $workspaceName + user is the issue. Somehow the $workspaceName is coupled to a "build:" user. My powershell runs with a different user than the workspace.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

- You have to delete the existing workspace, before you can create a second
- Deletion is tricky, because of the name of the workspace
- The name consists of `<workspacename>;Build\<collectionId>`
- Workspacename is available in the [list of the predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml): $Build_Repository_Tfvc_Workspace
- Collection Id was not obvious to me. I figured it out by checking which variable has which value.

In Powershell, getting files from another project can be achieved with:

```
$tf = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($env:AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY, "externals", "tf", "tf.exe")
$workspaceName = $env:Build_Repository_Tfvc_Workspace
$workspaceNameWithUser = $workspaceName + ";Build\" + $env:SYSTEM_COLLECTIONID
& $tf vc workspace /delete $workspaceNameWithUser
```

Now you can create a new workspace and a new mapping, like I mentioned in my question:

```
$collection = "well my collection..."
$tfsProjectTargetPath = "`$/projectB/subdir/branch"
$localWorkDir = $env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY
$workspaceName = "choose a new name"
& $tf vc workspace /new /location:local /permission:Public $workspaceName /collection:$collection /noprompt $commandLogin
& $tf vc workfold /unmap /workspace:$workspaceName $/ /collection:$collection /noprompt $commandLogin
& $tf vc workfold /map /workspace:$workspaceName $tfsProjectTargetPath $localWorkDir /collection:$collection /noprompt
& $tf vc get /recursive /overwrite $localWorkDir /noprompt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [TFVC Get](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sevaalekseyev.tfvcget&ssr=false#overview) extension which do it for you.

If you want to do it by yourself you can use the [Items - Get Items Batch Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/items/get-items-batch?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP), for example:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/tfvc/itembatch?api-version=5.1

{
  "itemDescriptors": [
    {
      "path": "$/Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC/AuthSample/AuthSample/Program.cs",
      "version": 5,
      "versionType": "changeset"
    },
    {
      "path": "$/Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC/AuthSample",
      "recursionLevel": "Full"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you know for sure that it is impossible via tf.exe? Is it really necessary to go with REST API? Seems a lot of extra workload to connect to azure devops when you are running inside azure devops.

Comment: I think it's do possible, need to check... what is the issue with the extension?

Comment: External software that has to be installed and maintained. Not sure if that is needed for this simple use case. I'd prefer a second mapping via UI over an extension. I know that works, but I can't manage mappings in Task Groups. I would like to use a Task Group to manage many builds at once.